# XML to XSL-FO C#.NET

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, xslt, xsl-fo

How can I convert/transform/create an xsl-fo file from an XML document using an xsl stylesheet i C#.NET?

What I want to achieve is a REST Service that is used to "print" a PDF to the browser. The XML is loaded in via another REST Service and the stylesheet is pre-defined and located in my project as a resource.

This is the code so far, just to demonstrate the structure I'm after: (Note that the return type String is just for troubleshooting and will be replaced once I get further)

```
    public String GetPDFList(String apiquery, String template)
    {
        String returnString;

        /* BUILD QUERY TO GET XML CONTENT */
        string returnUrl = api_url + apiquery + api_key;

        /* BUILD XML CONTENT TO DOCUMENT */
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(returnUrl);

        /* GENERATE XSL-FO FILE FROM XML AND XSL STYLESHEET */
        /* TODO */

        /* GENERATE PDF FROM XSL-FO FILE */
        /* TODO */

        /* RETURN PDF TO CLIENT */
        /* TODO */

        return returnUrl; 
    }
```

EDIT: I'm currently trying to achieve this using the fo.net library but I can't find any documentation on how to perform this single task of creating the xsl-fo file.

Comment: you have to use something like this library https://fonet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes I'm looking at fo.net as a library for this solution but I can't find any documentation or any examples on how to perform this step. I've seen an example of a whole project at codeplex (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/595650/Creating-PDF-documents-from-XML) but I can't seem to use it for modification. It seems a bit too complex for learning how to use the different functionalities. I should have been more clear in my question, I'm sorry for that and thanks for your comment!

Comment: From memory you would performa an normal xml => XSL-T conversion to generate your FO. However this does first require you know all the FO syntax in order for have your document to go through the FO parser to generate the PDF. I'll try an find you an example.  In short you are simply doing an XSL-T on an XML.

Comment: I've found my example, I'm using the FOP to generate the final pdf.  Have you looked at these? https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: Apache FOP is for Java though? fo.net is an apache port to work with c#? Also, I already have the xsl file to describe the styling of the output but I'm missing the link where I convert the xml to xsl-fo (using the xsl stylesheet). Or have I completley missunderstood the logic behind how this works?

Comment: http://www.cloudformatter.com/css2pdf is a REST-based, C# solution that uses RenderX XEPWin at the core for XML (created from HTML in browser) + XSL to FO to PDF. You can contact me offline at that website if you would like more information

Comment: FOP is for java originally but also works for .Net. the FO is just an xml/XSL-T that formats the final XML output. So for me I have an XSL-T which consumes my XML generating an FO ready document that feeds into FOP. Generating the FO is nothing much more than this: XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load("output.xsl");

// Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
xslt.Transform("books.xml", "books.html");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
XmlDocument oXML = new XmlDocument();

oXML = LoadXml("And xml string or do the load from file");

// if data loaded from memory save to disk first
oXML.Save(xmlpath)

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(FoXSLtPATH);

// Execute the transform and output the results to a file.
// Ready for the FO engine to generate PDF from
xslt.Transform(xmlpath, FoToConsumeOutputPath);
```

Comment: Thank you DubMan, I assume that oXML = LoadXml(...) can be replaced with: oXML.load(fromURL);? What should the FoXSLtPATH variable represent? where I want to store the fo-file? and lastly, the FoToConsumeOutputPath, what is that representing?

Comment: point one, yep, point two the FoXSLtPath is an input path for the XSL-t which you said you already had to apply to your XML, and point three, FoToConsumeOutputPath is an output path for where to put the output. This is what is then ready to feed into your FO parser creating the PDF. At least thats how mine work. This is then the output path I use to feed into FOP which generates my PDf documents.  Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry for my complete stupidity in this subject and thank you for your help. Do you know what might cause the service to throw this exception when doing the xslt.Transform?: {"Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java'."}. What happens is that the fo-file is created but not completed, meaning that it doesn't have all the closing tags etc. I assume that this exception might be the cause of it.

Comment: @JonathanLind, that exception means that your XSLT is not pure XSLT but rather relies on extension functions or extension objects specific to a particular XSLT processor, probably Xalan Java. You would need to rewrite the stylesheet code to pure XSLT or to XSLT + .NET extensions to be able to execute it with `XslCompiledTransform`.

Comment: @Martin Honnen, Thank you! You are absolutely right, I noticed I had some Java references in the xslt files. I'll mark this Question as answered and thank all of you for assisting me in solving this problem causing me so much headache:)